# Change which folders appear in Dash

Tags: unity-dash

I'm running 12.04

Currently when I hit the super key, I get a search bar, my recent apps, my recent files, and my Downloads directory.

Is there a way to change that to be my Programming directory, or whatever (ie. /home/me/Downloads -> /home/me/Programming)?